# Using jQuery $.inArray

Tags: jquery

I need to compare a dynamically created variable against an array of static values. As the variable is dynamically generated I can't do something like

```
if ($.inArray('example', myArray) != -1)
{
  // found it
}
```

What I have so far is this

```
 //This runs for each link in the .lc_Cell element
  $('.lc_Cell > p > a').attr('href', function(i, href) {

        //Grab the link and split it into chunks at each occurence of '&'
        var arr = href.split('&');
        console.log(arr);

        //Keep a portion of the link as a var, this is always a 4 digit number
        //For the purposes of this question lets say this value is going to be 7473 
        var trId = arr[1].slice(-4); 
        console.log(trId);

        //Populating my array of desired numbers to search against
        var validTR = [7473, 7474, 7475, 7476, 7477, 7478, 7479, 7480, 7481, 7482, 7483, 7484, 7485, 7486, 7487, 7488, 7489, 7490, 7491, 7492, 7493, 7494, 7495, 7351]; 
        console.log(validTR);       


        //Compare the sliced value from the link against the array
        var testingID = $.inArray(trId, validTR)
        console.log(testingID);
}
```

My testingID in the console consistently keeps returning -1, even if the the value in trId is one contained within the array.

Ultimately, I need to be able to get a positive value for testingID so I can write an if statement to do something afterwards.

Comment: As per the docs: "The comparison between values is strict." (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/).


Your `trId` is a string, the array values are numbers. Try wrapping your array values in quotes to make them strings or cast all to strings or numbers

Comment: Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nedq5jcr/

Comment: @BrettGregson you're the man! Just got it working properly by parsing my variable to an integer. Thank you for pointing this out to me, completely overlooked that! Will have a look at your fiddle and see if it's cleaner than what I just whipped up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray):

> The comparison between values is strict.

Your `trId` value is a string, the array values are numbers. This is because `jQuery.attr()` [returns a string](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) (except in special cases).

Try wrapping your array values in quotes to make them strings or cast all to strings or numbers:

```
trId = parseInt(trId, 10);
```

or

```
var validTR = ["7473", "7474", ...
```

A fiddle demonstrating the problem can be [found here](https://jsfiddle.net/nedq5jcr/)

Answer (score 0):

- The `validTR` array contains only numbers.
- The return value of `slice()` will be a string.

A string representation of a number is not the same as a number, so it won't be found when you search the array.

```js
const array = [1,2,3];
const number = 2;
const string = "2";

console.log("A", $.inArray(string, array));
console.log("B", $.inArray(number, array));
console.log("C", $.inArray(+string, array));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Either populate the array with strings, or convert the string to a number.